# Stock market. Code can´t read CSV format/layout correctly. Python

Tags: python, csv, stock

```
    df = pd.read_csv('gme_quotedata.csv', sep='\s+', header=None, skiprows=0,)

    df.columns = ['1stCol']

    spot_price = df['1stCol'][0].split(',')[1]
    spot_price = float(spot_price.split('Last:')[1])

    df = df.iloc[3:]

    new = df["1stCol"].str.split(",", n = 21, expand = True)
    new.columns = ['ExpirationDate','Calls','CallLastSale','CallNet','CallBid','CallAsk','CallVol','CallIV','CallDelta','CallGamma','CallOpenInt','CallStrike','Puts','PutLastSale','PutNet','PutBid','PutAsk','PutVol','PutIV','PutDelta','PutGamma','PutOpenInt']
```

https://www.cboe.com/delayed_quotes/gme/quote_table

On CBOE website there is optionchain for stocks. Scroll to the bottom of it and press download CSV. My code seem to not be able to read the format/layout of the CSV correctly. What´s wrong with my code above and can someone rewrite it to be able to read the CSV?

Problem = can´t open the CSV with this code.
probably wrong order on the data compared to code.

Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include and example of what is incorrect and what you expect.

Comment: Please copy-paste the first few lines from that CSV, and pay attention the lines before the actual table data: there-in lies your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I look at the CSV I see these first 6 lines:

```
GameStop Corp.,Last: 153.02,Change:  4.45
"Date: January 3, 2022, 4:32 PM EST",Bid: 151.82,Ask: 153.48,Size: 1*1,"Volume: 1,394,206"
Expiration Date,Calls,Last Sale,Net,Bid,Ask,Volume,IV,Delta,Gamma,Open Interest,Strike,Puts,Last Sale,Net,Bid,Ask,Volume,IV,Delta,Gamma,Open Interest
Fri Jan 07 2022,GME220107C00149000,...
Fri Jan 07 2022,GME220107C00150000,...
```

I don't have Pandas installed, or really know it, but I can see that you're giving `read_csv()` bad *parameters* in your first line of code:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('gme_quotedata.csv', sep='\s+', header=None, skiprows=0,)
...
```

- The separator is a comma (`','`), and not "one or more spaces" (`'\s+'`).
- There very much is a *header*, and more than one line, *row*, that should be *skipped*.

Number-one priority for you is to take a critical look at your data and understand its *composition*.

Number-two priority is to  check **[read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)** documentation, looking specifically for the **sep**, **headers**, and **skiprows** parameters.

`','` is the default for **sep**, and your data has a comma, so you can omit that... `read_csv()` already expects a comma, you don't need to try and give it special guidance there.

**headers** and **skiprows** may be confusing, so maybe just cut out the first 4 lines so your CSV is "pure data" with no meta data.

Comment: Thank you :) I have a little problem knowing to where i should cut out, my file look messier then yours. I tried cuting out everything above Fri Jan 07 in your text above but it´s not working. was that right or to where should i cut out? :) Thank you.

Comment: Is there automated way removing all metadata in a CSV file? :) thank you

Comment: I downloaded and copy-pasted the file you pointed to. If you download that file again, does it still look different?

Comment: Also, what did you learn about the **sep**, **headers**, and **skiprows** parameters? Try playing with those. If you're new to coding, welcome! It's an interactive experience, and requires trial, error, and perseverance.